# Getting null value in controller when passing the list through routvalues (html.action)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When i pass  list  through routevalues in "Html.Action" I am always getting null value in controller. But when i pass interger,string or bool i am getting the correct value.

How to pass list through routevalues?

My View is

```
@Html.Action("ViewTeam", "ProjectTeamManagement", new { Team = @Model.ProjecTeam})
```

The controller is

```
    public ActionResult ViewTeam(List<ProjectTeam> Team)
    {
        return PartialView("ViewTeam",Team);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the html.action will have the "Get" Method... It is not possible to pass the list to the Get method through routevalues.  We should use Ajax Post method to pass the list.